# executing asynctask as a fragmentactivity starts (doesn't execute)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);     

  return myFragmentView;
}
```

I normally have this `onCreateView` executing and all my code was in it, due to a recommendation I took and inserted the remainder of my code into `onViewCreated`. I am not complaining but the exact same thing happened. The `ASyncTask` doesn't execute as I open the fragment activity. Here's my `onViewCreated` :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Requ connReq = new Requ();
      connReq.execute(); //go go power rangers
}
```

It's not that complicated after all but for some reason it doesn't launch my asynctask. It 'shows' the `ProgressDialog` which begins in `onPreExecute` and dismisses in `onPostExecute`. So you could say that it just won't execute my `doInBackground` What am I doing wrong with this thing? I just want my ASyncTask to execute as I open the fragment and load my data.
I'd really appreciate the help, thanks in advance. I searched all over the place but I really couldn't find a proper solution for this, I thought there'd be one.

PS: the asynctask works just well when I add the execution to an `onClickListener`

my asynctask:

```
private class Requ extends AsyncTask<String, String[], String[]> {

    final String pdMessage = getString(R.string.pd_wait);

    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute () {
        pd.setMessage(pdMessage);
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

        String[] connResult;

          final String SipUrlStr = getString(R.string.sip_url);

          String bsm = "";
          String bst= "";
          String hs= "";
          String as= "";

        try {
              JSONTokener SipTokener = new JSONTokener(Sources.httpConnGet(SipUrlStr).toString());
                    JSONArray SipArray=new JSONArray(SipTokener);

                    for(int i=0; i<(SipArray.length()); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject json_obj_sip = yeniSipArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        bsm = json_obj_sip.getString("mt");
                        bst = json_obj_sip.getString("tt");
                        hs = json_obj_sip.getString("pta");
                        as = json_obj_sip.getString("pta2");
                    }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            bsm = getString(R.string.def_sip);
            bst = getString(R.string.def_sip);
            hs = getString(R.string.has);
            as = getString(R.string.ass);
        }

        connRes = new String[]{bsm, bst, hs, as};
        return connRes;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] connRes) {
        super.onPostExecute(connRes);


        res[0] = connRes[0];
        res[1] = connRes[1];
        res[2] = connRes[2];
        res[3] = connRes[3];
        res[4] = connRes[4];
        res[5] = connRes[5];
        res[6] = connRes[6];
        res[7] = connRes[7];
        res[8] = connRes[8];
        res[9] = connRes[9];
        res[10] = connRes[10];
        res[11] = connRes[11];
        pd.dismiss();
    }


}
```

Comment: post your asynctask as well

Comment: @vipulmittal here you are sir

Comment: It executes all right if `onPreExecute()` gets called. However, you're catching all `Exception`s and ignoring them. At least add some logging in the catch block to better figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @laalto hi, I'm sorry for the late reply. really. My try and catch blocks actually work fine, now I realised that my doinbackground launches just fine, it just won't return the data the first time. If I refresh the fragment somehow after it failed, it loads just fine. It's like it does not have enough time to load the first time.

Comment: @laalto well, I found the solution, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out it was about the cycle. Since I was trying to launch `AsyncTask` on `MainThread` the code flew by and `AsyncTask` didn't have enough time to finish its job. And one absolutely shouldn't make the thread wait for `AsyncTask`. It's against the first rule of `AsyncTask`. 'not doing that.' Okay, so I moved the execution of `AsyncTask` to `onCreate()` that way it will have more time and it won't execute everytime I open the fragment...

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      Requ connReq = new Requ();
      connReq.execute(); //go go power rangers

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }
```

then, this is important, I moved all my code into `onPostExecute()` method of `AsyncTask`. If you want to change a variable or change a view you should just do it `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting your async task in

```
onActivityCreated
```

Function

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle b){

super.onActivityCreated(b);
// Execute here
//Get views
getView().findViewById(<ID>);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way for introducing views programmatically in onactivitycreated? Lile view.findviewbyid...

Comment: you can call getView() in onActivityCreated and call findViewById on it.